# base64_decode produces a string containing null characters

Tags: php, string, base64

I have the following string that is being provided to me by a data vendor:

> RwBVAEkARAAgACgANwBmAGEAZAA4AGEANgBhAGEAOQA3ADAANAAwAGEAYgBiAGUAMQBiAGEAZQBjAGMAZgBiADgAMwA4AGEAMABkACkAIABuAG8AdAAgAGYAbwB1AG4AZAAgAGkAbgAgAFEAIAB0AGEAYgBsAGUALgA=

The documentation indicates that it is a Base64 encoded string.  When I run base64_decode on this string, and look at the return value, I see a lot of null characters distributed in the string:

> `$encodedString = "RwBVAEkARAAgACgANwBmAGEAZAA4AGEANgBhAGEAOQA3ADAANAAwAGEAYgBiAGUAMQBiAGEAZQBjAGMAZgBiADgAMwA4AGEAMABkACkAIABuAG8AdAAgAGYAbwB1AG4AZAAgAGkAbgAgAFEAIAB0AGEAYgBsAGUALgA=";
>   $decodedString = base64_decode($encodedString);
>   print var_export($decodedString,true);`

Output:

> 'G' . "\0" . 'U' . "\0" . 'I' . "\0" . 'D' . "\0" . ' ' . "\0" . '(' . "\0" . '7' . "\0" . 'f' . "\0" . 'a' . "\0" . 'd' . "\0" . '8' . "\0" . 'a' . "\0" . '6' . "\0" . 'a' . "\0" . 'a' . "\0" . '9' . "\0" . '7' . "\0" . '0' . "\0" . '4' . "\0" . '0' . "\0" . 'a' . "\0" . 'b' . "\0" . 'b' . "\0" . 'e' . "\0" . '1' . "\0" . 'b' . "\0" . 'a' . "\0" . 'e' . "\0" . 'c' . "\0" . 'c' . "\0" . 'f' . "\0" . 'b' . "\0" . '8' . "\0" . '3' . "\0" . '8' . "\0" . 'a' . "\0" . '0' . "\0" . 'd' . "\0" . ')' . "\0" . ' ' . "\0" . 'n' . "\0" . 'o' . "\0" . 't' . "\0" . ' ' . "\0" . 'f' . "\0" . 'o' . "\0" . 'u' . "\0" . 'n' . "\0" . 'd' . "\0" . ' ' . "\0" . 'i' . "\0" . 'n' . "\0" . ' ' . "\0" . 'Q' . "\0" . ' ' . "\0" . 't' . "\0" . 'a' . "\0" . 'b' . "\0" . 'l' . "\0" . 'e' . "\0" . '.' . "\0" . ''

What I expect to see is:

> GUID (7fad8a6aa97040abbe1baeccfb838a0d) not found in Q table.

I now have to run a string replace to eliminate the null characters so that I can perform string matching etc to evaluate the content of the string:

`$cleanString = str_replace("\0","",$decodedString);`

Here are my questions:

1. Until I finally decided to do a var_export(), print and var_dump both reported the string without the null characters.  I do understand that these functions cannot/do not print null characters, but how would I have detected a string packed with null characters without having done the var_export and observed the issue visually?
2. I chased a lot of red-herrings on encoding.  Is base64_decode the wrong approach?  Is there anyway to eliminate the additional step of the str_replace?
3. What is the technical term for a string that contains null characters (turns out PITA is too general)?  I've wasted too much time trying to describe to google what I was looking at, and think perhaps there is a technical description that differentiates "normal" strings from this abomination I've been dealing with.

Your advice is much appreciated.

Shaheeb R.

Comment: Sounds more like a problem with the vendor's data than yours.  Can they offer any insight?

Comment: This particular vendor has been challenging to work with.  I am not hopeful that they will even acknowledge the issue, let alone support us in providing a solution.  Moreover, I want to be sure that it is, in fact, the vendor's issue.  It seems bizarre to me that they would encode a string with the null characters on purpose, so I want to give them the benefit of the doubt and first verify that I am not missing something.

Comment: Agree with @thetaiko, the base64_encode value for your sentence is "R1VJRCAoN2ZhZDhhNmFhOTcwNDBhYmJlMWJhZWNjZmI4MzhhMGQpIG5vdCBmb3VuZCBpbiBRIHRhYmxlLg==", not the vendor's data you said. They really send you null chars. For your 3 points: 1) By a var_export() because you can't see invisible chars or by file_put_contents() and read the file with an IDE that can show you invisible chars (Notepad++?). 2) On my knows, there's nothing you can do better than str_replace("\0", '', base64_decode($string));. 3) If I were you, I googled "base64 php string null chars" but I would have wasted my time too.

Comment: And probably the vendor uses UTF-16 while you're using UTF-8. This can probably be the source of the error